# Django -- Using a list to pass values to model.objects.only() in django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to get only some fields from a queryset based on the input of a form:

```
report_query_values = QueryDict(request.META['QUERY_STRING']).keys
        return render_to_response('custom_report_query.html', {'CIs': CI_table.objects.only('ci_identifier','chargeback_number_id','install_date') }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I get the keys from the querydict and those are the fields from the DB that I want to return to the template.
If I use some sample names as in the code above, it works fine.
But my goal would be something like this:

```
'CIs': CI_table.objects.only(report_query_values)
```

Any ideas of how can I get that?

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decompose the list.

`'CIs': CI_table.objects.only(*report_query_values)`

Comment: Thanks, so simple is going to be awesome, but getting this errors when using that code: only() argument after * must be a sequence, not builtin_function_or_method

Comment: @isaapm you need to call the `keys` - it is a method: `keys()`.